Convert JSON to CSV, repeating parent value
There's a lot of discussion to convert JSON to CSV with jq, but can't find my situation.
2 points really blocking me :

Get key and value of valuePerDay by row
Sort valuePerDay keys to unsure values always in the same position

I assume this JSON give the valuePerDay always the same keys for each arr.
I have this JSON :
{
  "prop1": "val1",
  "prop2": "val2",
  "arr": [
    {
      "arrProp1": "arr1Prop1",
      "arrProp2": "arr1Prop2",
      "valuePerDay": {
        "2024-01-01": 1,
        "2024-01-02": 2,
        "2024-01-03": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "arrProp1": "arr2Prop1",
      "arrProp2": "arr2Prop2",
      "valuePerDay": {
        "2024-01-02": 22,
        "2024-01-01": 11,
        "2024-01-03": 33
      }
    },
    {
      "arrProp1": "arr3Prop1",
      "arrProp2": "arr3Prop1",
      "valuePerDay": {
        "2024-01-03": 333,
        "2024-01-01": 111,
        "2024-01-02": 222
      }
    }
  ]
}

Here is my actual JQ, but values are multiply by keys
.prop1 as $prop1
| .prop2 as $prop2
| .arr[]
  | .arrProp1 as $arrProp1
  | .arrProp2 as $arrProp2
  | .valuePerDay
    | keys_unsorted[] as $key
    | .[] as $value
| [$prop1,$prop2,$arrProp1,$arrProp2,$key,$value] 
| @csv

Which give me :
"prop1","prop2","arrProp1","arrProp2","valuePerDay","value"
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-01",1
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-01",2
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-01",3
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-02",1
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-02",2
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-02",3
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-03",1
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-03",2
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-03",3
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-01",11
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-01",22
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-01",33
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-02",11
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-02",22
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-02",11
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-03",33
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-03",22
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-03",33
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-01",111
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-01",222
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-01",333
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-02",111
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-02",222
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-02",333
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-03",111
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-03",222
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-03",333

And I want :
"prop1","prop2","arrProp1","arrProp2","valuePerDay","value"
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-01",1
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-02",2
"val1","val2","arr1Prop1","arr1Prop2","2024-01-03",3
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-01",11
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-02",22
"val1","val2","arr2Prop1","arr2Prop2","2024-01-03",33
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-01",111
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-02",222
"val1","val2","arr3Prop1","arr3Prop2","2024-01-03",333


With .[] as $value, you iterate again (after keys_unsorted[] as $key) over all items. Replace it with .[$key] as $value to just go into the one iterated over the first time:
.prop1 as $prop1
| .prop2 as $prop2
| .arr[]
  | .arrProp1 as $arrProp1
  | .arrProp2 as $arrProp2
  | .valuePerDay
    | keys_unsorted[] as $key
    | .[$key] as $value
| [$prop1,$prop2,$arrProp1,$arrProp2,$key,$value] 
| @csv

Demo
Here's a similar approach with simplifications for the variable binding, and the use of to_entries to get an array of key-value pairs:
. as {$prop1, $prop2} | .arr[]
| . as {$arrProp1, $arrProp2} | .valuePerDay | to_entries[]
| [$prop1, $prop2, $arrProp1, $arrProp2, .key, .value] | @csv

Demo
And here's another one without using variables by successively concatenating the final array:
[.prop1, .prop2] + (.arr[] | [.arrProp1, .arrProp2] + (
  .valuePerDay | to_entries[] | [.key, .value]
)) | @csv

Demo
